# JavaScript - more efficient checking object - if...else or try...catch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, try-catch

What is the best way to check if data exist before next expression? For example if I have an object like:

```
test = {
    "CompanyData": {
        "Address": {
            "RegisteredAddress": {
                "Country": null,
                "City": null,
                "Street": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And possible is also:

```
test = {
    "CompanyData": null
}
```

and I need to check if Country is "xyz".

What is the best way? For example:

1. `if (test.CompanyData && test.CompanyData.Address && test.CompanyData.RegisteredAddress){...}`
2. Some outside function that checks if key is in object
3. Short `try { if (test.CompanyData.Address.RegisteredAddress.Country == "xyz") {...}} ... catch(){}`

All options works fine, but they seems to me not the best practices.

Comment: use `try/catch` if you want to handle errors. Don't use it for flow control where you induce an error deliberately just to go to the `catch` block. Use `if`/`else` instead as that's what you're effectively re-creating but with errors.

Comment: `catch(){}` is a really bad idea

Answer (score 4):

The most concise and arguable the most idiomatic way is to use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`):

```
if (test?.CompanyData?.Address?.RegisteredAddress?.Country === 'xyz') {
  // ...
}
```